# unable to create custom layout objects (python)

Tags: python, tkinter

i'm trying to create a custom label for my python prject but when I run the code, the IDE send me an error.

this is my class where I create the function with the custom label:

```
from tkinter import *

class designtools:

   def create_label(window, name_of_label, row, column):
        label = Label(window, name_of_label)
        label.grid(row = row, column = column)
        return label
```

and this is the call of the method:

```
label_location = designtools.create_label(window, "location", 0, 0)
```

and this is the output of the IDE

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\programma orari\programma_orari.py", line 19, in <module>
    label_location = designtools.create_label(window, "location", 0, 0)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\programma orari\designtools.py", line 6, in create_label
    label = Label(window, name_of_label)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3143, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2564, in __init__
    classes = [(k, v) for k, v in cnf.items() if isinstance(k, type)]
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

thanks for help.

Comment: Give 2nd argument name like this `text="location"`

Comment: the IDE give me the error  "positional argument follows keywords argument "

Comment: You need to give here like this `label = Label(window, text = name_of_label)`

Comment: I want to create a function that creates a custom label to avoid wasting code

Comment: yes you can do that  declare like this `label = Label(window, text = name_of_label)` and pass the data `label_location = designtools.create_label(window, "location", 0, 0)` . Moreover you don't have an init method in your class I would recommend having the method as static or declare method locally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming `name_of_label` is the text you want on your label.

you can implement it like this:

```
import tkinter as tk

class designtools: 
    
    @staticmethod
    def create_label(window, text, row, column): 

        label = tk.Label(master=window, text=text)
        label.grid(row = row, column = column)
        return label
```

then call it in this way:

`label1 = designtools.create_label(window, "my_text", 0, 0)`

this label should show up with my text on it.

Comment: give this error:         Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\programma orari\programma_orari.py", line 19, in <module>
    label_location = designtools.create_label(window, "location", 0, 0)
TypeError: create_label() missing 1 required positional argument: 'column'

Comment: if you wnat to use the create_label just like another function and not like a class function then make it static function! just add the `@staticmethod` decorator. Also, I have edited the answer.

Comment: I try with the static method but it gives me the same start error

Comment: Using `StringVar` inside `create_label()` is not necessary because it cannot be accessed outside the function.

Comment: I realised it later, using `text = my_text` would be better! editted the answer. thanks @acw1668